# Trying to move servo motor via 3 buttons

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, button

[image: The wiring]

I am having some difficulties in trying to make my servo motor move to a specific angle based on the button pressed.

For example, having the motor start at 0 degrees and then having it move to 180 when the 3rd button is pressed, have it return to 0 degrees when the first button is pressed, and have it go to 90 degrees when the second button is pressed, etc, etc.

I can't tell if I am going about this all wrong or not with my code, so if anyone could provide some assistance with this it would be a great help

EDIT: Added the wiring as a just in case

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;
int angle = 0;
int anglestep = 10;

#define FIRST 2 // pin 2 is connected to 1st floor button
#define SECOND 3 // pin 3 is connected to 2nd floor button
#define THIRD 4 // pin 4 is connected to 3rd floor button
#define SIGNAL 10

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
myservo.attach(10);
myservo.write(angle);
pinMode(2,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(3,INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(4,INPUT_PULLUP);
Serial.println("Lift/Descend");
}

void loop()
{
while (digitalRead(FIRST) == LOW)
    {
    if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90) //2to1
        {
        angle = angle - anglestep;
            if (angle < 0)
            {
            angle = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            myservo.write(angle);
            Serial.print("Moved to: ");
            Serial.print(angle);
            Serial.println(" degree");
            }
        }
    else if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180) //3to1
    {
        angle = angle - anglestep;
            if (angle < 0)
            {
            angle = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            myservo.write(angle);
            Serial.print("Moved to: ");
            Serial.print(angle);
            Serial.println(" degree");
            }
    }
    else //1on1
    {
        angle = 0;
    }

}
while (digitalRead(SECOND) == LOW)
    {
    if (angle > 90 && angle <= 180) //3to2
        {
        angle = angle - anglestep;
        if (angle > 90)
            {
            angle = 90;
            }
        else
        {
        myservo.write(angle);
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(angle);
        Serial.println(" degree");
        }
    }
    else if (angle > 0 && angle < 90) //1to2
        {
        angle = angle + anglestep;
        if (angle < 90)
            {
            angle = 90;
            }
        else
        {
        myservo.write(angle);
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(angle);
        Serial.println(" degree");
        }
    }
    else
    {//2on2//
    angle = 90;
    }
}

while (digitalRead(THIRD) == LOW)
{
    if (angle > 0 && angle <= 90) //1to3
    {
        angle = angle + anglestep;
        if (angle > 180)
            {
            angle = 180;
            }
        else
        {
        myservo.write(angle);
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(angle);
        Serial.println(" degree");
        }
    }
    else if (angle > 90 && angle < 180)
    {//2to3
        angle = angle + anglestep;
        if (angle > 180)
            {
            angle = 180;
            }
        else
        {
        myservo.write(angle);
        Serial.print("Moved to: ");
        Serial.print(angle);
        Serial.println(" degree");
        }
    }
    else
        {
        angle = 180;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? You forgot to describe, what  does not work as expected and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really overthinking things there. A servo will move to an angle if you just give it the final angle to move to. You don't need to nudge it to the final angle by visiting every angle in between, and you don't need to know what angle it's at currently.

You can simply do:

```
if (digitalRead(FIRST) == LOW) {
    myservo.write(0);
}

if (digitalRead(SECOND) == LOW) {
    myservo.write(90);
}

if (digitalRead(THIRD) == LOW) {
    myservo.write(180);
}
```

However if you wanted to slow the movement down, which would entail moving the servo in smaller steps, I would separate out the current angle and positioning from the buttons, which would set a *desired* angle.  Something more like:

```
static uint8_t desiredAngle = 0;
static uint8_t currentAngle = 0;
static uint32_t timestamp = millis();

// Choose a new desired angle
if (digitalRead(FIRST) == LOW) {
    desiredAngle = 0;
}

if (digitalRead(SECOND) == LOW) {
    desiredAngle = 90;
}

if (digitalRead(THIRD) == LOW) {
    desiredAngle = 180;
}

// Every 10ms "tick" the servo towards the desired 
// angle by 1 degree
if (millis() - timestamp >= 10) {
    timestamp = millis();
    if (desiredAngle > currentAngle) {
        currentAngle++;
        myservo.write(currentAngle);
    } else if (desiredAngle < currentAngle) {
        currentAngle--;
        myservo.write(currentAngle);
    }
}
```